# How to create <select> in editable datatable in metronic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use `<select>` in editable datatable.

I use this editable in metronic theme: [link](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme_rtl/admin_2_material_design/table_datatables_editable.html)

This code in JS file:

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
        aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
        var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

        jqTds[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
        jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
        jqTds[3].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';
        jqTds[4].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[4] + '">';
        jqTds[5].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[5] + '">';
        jqTds[6].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[6] + '">';
        jqTds[7].innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[7] + '">';
        jqTds[11].innerHTML = '<a class="edit" href="">Save</a>';
        jqTds[12].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel" href="">Cancel</a>';
    }

function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
        var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 1, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 2, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 3, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 4, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[4].value, nRow, 5, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[5].value, nRow, 6, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[6].value, nRow, 7, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 11, false);
        oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="delete" href=""></a>', nRow, 12, false);
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }
```

How to use `<select>` Instead `<input>` in JS file?

```
<select>
   <option value="1">Men</option>
   <option value="2">Women</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This might help with your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44316326/3175526

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerHTML` to change an element.

```
function editRow(oTable, nRow) {  

      jqTds[1].innerHTML = ' <select id="ddltesttype"><option>Tox</option></select>';
      jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input id="txtcomm" type="text" value="' + aData[4] + '">';
    }
```

Than save it as:

```
 function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
            debugger
            var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            var jqselect = $('select', nRow);
            console.log(jqselect)
            // oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            var selecteditem = jqselect[1]["selectedOptions"][0]["childNodes"][0]["data"];
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqselect[0].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(selecteditem, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqselect[2].value, nRow, 3, false);
}
```

Comment: Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .